# Applying colors on shared vertices

Tags: c++, opengl

```
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
int width = 250;
int height = 250;
int border = 10;

int top     = y + border;
int bottom  = y + height;
int left    = x + border;
int right   = x + width;

static int vertices[] = {
    x,                  y,                  //0
    right,              y,                  //1
    right,              bottom,             //2
    x,                  bottom,             //3

    left,               top,                //4
    right - border,     top,                //5
    right - border,     bottom - border,    //6
    left,               bottom - border,    //7

    left,               top + (height - border - border) * 0.5,
    right - border,     top + (height - border - border) * 0.5
};


static unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 4, 5, //top border
    5, 1, 6, 2, //right border
    2, 6, 3, 7, //bottom border
    7, 4, 3, 0, //left border

    4, 5, 8, 9,
    8, 9, 7, 6,
};

static unsigned char colors[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,

    0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xff, 0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
    0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
    0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
    0x00, 0xff, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
};
```

My current undesired output:

[image]

Is it possible to apply a single color on a single quad in this kind of implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common misconception that "Vertex" means "position". A vertex is the whole combination of its attributes, among them position, color, texture coordinate, etc. etc. If one of the attributes between two vertices differs, the vertices are not the same.

*If you want to give the two quads different solid colors, they don't share vertices.*

I think the rest should be obvious.

Comment: so I should repeat vertices then?

Comment: @mr5 Not repeat, as they are not the same, obviously.

Comment: @user1095108 I mean, add more vertices than my current one?